# How to use "send" or "public_send" for a 'Model' name in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanna use `send`  or `public_send` for a `Model` name.
but while I use `send`  or `public_send`, I get the following error:

```
send("User").all
#NoMethodError: undefined method 'User' for main:Object
```

Is there any way to handle this problem? (even without `send`  or `public_send`) if there is, please help me handle it.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to get class name from string, something like this will work:

```
Object.const_get("User").all
```

This will throw an error if class is not found:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User
```

If you want something that will return `nil` instead of raising error, you can try:

```
"User".safe_constantize
```

Answer (score 0):

`send` or `public_send` are only for method call. If u want to dynamically change the model name u can do smth like `"model_name".constantize.all`